# IPad Application crashes on device

Tags: ipad, uitableview, ios4

I'm developing an app for IPad which contains `UITableView`. The app works fine on simulator but it crashes on device when installed and runs for the 1st time. When I try to run the app 2nd time it works fine.I'm not able to make out what the problem is .
The same code works fine on IPhone but it crashes on IPad.
I'm using the following code for table

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *MythoViewCellIdentifier = @"MythoViewCellIdentifier ";

UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MythoViewCellIdentifier];



if (cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];        
}

[self getMythoData];


UIImageView *imgLogo =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1,0,37,35)];
imgLogo.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bullet_swastik.png"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgLogo];



UITextView *txtDetails =[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(37,34,740,200)];
txtDetails.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
txtDetails.editable=NO;
txtDetails.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25.0];
[cell.contentView addSubview:txtDetails];



//    adding details to the cell
txtDetails.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[FinalmythoData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


[txtDetails release];

return cell;
}




 I'm getting the following error

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000 Crashed Thread:  0




    Thanks
```

Comment: Where did it crashes exactly ?

Comment: Which _line_ does it crash on? The debugger should be able to tell you that. If the debugger has _not_ told you, how do you know it's in the above code?

Comment: Coz the app crashes wherever it contains table.The view which does not contains table works fine

Comment: array count ie [FinalmythoData count];

Answer (score 0):

> The app works fine on simulator but it crashes on device when installed and runs for the 1st time. When I try to run the app 2nd time it works fine.

Delete the app from your simulator, clean your project, rebuild, and run again the app. Chances are it will crash on the simulator as well.

Comment: strange. then post the output you get on the console or the crash log.

Comment: exe_bad_access(sigsegv). I'm getting this output

Comment: you sure have more... what is the stack trace, etc. please, paste it at the end of your question...

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that your app is not loading any heavy data(image etc) that might be the reason for crash.

Run your app on device and confirm that it is not running under low memory using Instrument or any other tool.

Comment: Its not showing any low memory warning on simulator and device